# Why does None lack a docstring?

Tags: python, documentation, language-design

As far as I'm aware, every builtin object in Python has a docstring. Except, as I just found out today, None. Why is this?

Comment: *shrug*. Does it *need* one?

Comment: Because it needs `None` ;-)

Comment: Here a nice article about `None` http://adamj.eu/tech/2014/09/20/python-concepts-part-none/

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do `int` and `str`?

Comment: @Schilcote: well, you can actually *do* something by calling those types. You can't with `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sure, but then, why not have a docstring saying that? May as well make that the answer.

Comment: @Schilcote: I've remembered something else, now have enough to make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`None` has no other function than to *exist*. It is *one* instance, not a type, while other built-ins are invariably *callable* or are instances of something that is.

Strings, numbers, booleans, etc. all have a callable type object, that often has specific conversion functionality as well (`bool()`, `int()`, `str()`). `None` doesn't; it's type doesn't produce anything because there is just the one instance:

```
>>> type(None)
<type 'NoneType'>
>>> type(None)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

`None` is not the only such object. `Ellipsis` and `NotImplemented` are other such objects:

```
>>> Ellipsis.__doc__ is None
True
>>> NotImplemented.__doc__ is None
True
>>> type(Ellipsis)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'ellipsis' instances
>>> type(NotImplemented)()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: cannot create 'NotImplementedType' instances
```

They are all *sentinels*, objects that signal a specific state or value, but are not useful outside of that function.

As such, they may have meaning in how they are used, not how they are created. The correct place to document this is the [*Datamodel* reference documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), not in docstrings.